# Jenkins build application docker image using Gradle script . Connection reset by peer at Socke file=/run/docker.sock

Tags: docker, grails, jenkins, gradle

I have Grails project, I was able to build and create docker image on my machine. Now trying to run the same steps in Jenkins pipeline. It's failing with below error message.

```
   pipeline {
            agent any          
            stages {               
                stage('Check Out Code') {
                    environment {
                        DEBUG_FLAGS = '-g'
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo 'Check Out..'
                        git url: https://github.com/sfgroups/grails-as-docker-image.git

                    }
                }
                stage('Build') {
                    steps {
                        timestamps {
                            ansiColor('xterm') {
                                echo 'Building..'
                                sh 'chmod +x gradlew'
                                sh './gradlew clean buildImage'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }          
        }
```

**Exception:**

```
14:38:59 Using tag 'grails-sample/grails docker build:0.1' for image.
14:39:01 [dockerjava-jaxrs-async-0] INFO org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: Connection reset by peer at Socket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=0][fd=java.io.FileDescriptor@5d7de1fa; file=/run/docker.sock; connected=true; bound=false]
14:39:01 [dockerjava-jaxrs-async-0] ERROR com.github.dockerjava.core.async.ResultCallbackTemplate - Error during callback
14:39:01 org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:187)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:435)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:448)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:349)
14:39:01    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.async.POSTCallbackNotifier.response(POSTCallbackNotifier.java:29)
14:39:01    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.async.AbstractCallbackNotifier.call(AbstractCallbackNotifier.java:50)
14:39:01    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.async.AbstractCallbackNotifier.call(AbstractCallbackNotifier.java:24)
14:39:01    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
14:39:01    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
14:39:01    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
14:39:01    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
14:39:01 Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:108)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
14:39:01    ... 18 more
14:39:01 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer at Socket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=0][fd=java.io.FileDescriptor@5d7de1fa; file=/run/docker.sock; connected=true; bound=false]
14:39:01    at org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocketImpl$AFUNIXOutputStream.write(AFUNIXSocketImpl.java:260)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:124)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:136)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:167)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.flushCacheWithAppend(ChunkedOutputStream.java:122)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.write(ChunkedOutputStream.java:179)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:229)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:299)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderWriter.writeTo(ReaderWriter.java:116)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeTo(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:79)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InputStreamProvider.writeTo(InputStreamProvider.java:105)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InputStreamProvider.writeTo(InputStreamProvider.java:60)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
14:39:01    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.filter.LoggingFilter.aroundWriteTo(LoggingFilter.java:300)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:517)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:499)
14:39:01    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$2.writeTo(ApacheConnector.java:583)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RequestEntityProxy.writeTo(RequestEntityProxy.java:121)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:160)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
14:39:01    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
14:39:01    ... 20 more
14:39:01 Caused by: org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocketException: Connection reset by peer
14:39:01    at org.newsclub.net.unix.NativeUnixSocket.write(Native Method)
14:39:01    at org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocketImpl$AFUNIXOutputStream.write(AFUNIXSocketImpl.java:251)
14:39:01    ... 48 more
14:39:01 :buildImage FAILED
14:39:01 
14:39:01 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
14:39:01 
14:39:01 * What went wrong:
14:39:01 Execution failed for task ':buildImage'.
14:39:01 > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
14:39:01 
14:39:01 * Try:
14:39:01 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
14:39:01 
14:39:01 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
14:39:01 
14:39:01 Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
14:39:01 See https://docs.gradle.org/4.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
14:39:01 
14:39:01 BUILD FAILED in 30s
14:39:01 12 actionable tasks: 12 executed
```

Comment: Check your server-side docker logs for more hints: `journalctl -u docker | grep error`. There has to be something wrong with your client setup, e.g. "... repository name must be lowercase".